# How I can update product items of an order where the product is discountable?

Tags: laravel

the Order model `hasmany` `items` relation and the item `belongsto` a `product`;

the items table is:
**id - order_id - product_id - coupon_id**

the coupon column is nullable and I want to add the coupon_id to products that are `discountable`. the `discountable` property in the products table is boolean.

this code update all `coupn_id`:

```
 $order->items()->update([
   "coupen_id" => $coupen->id,
]);
```

Here I can get those products:

```
      $items = $order->items;
      $discountable_products = $items->map(function ($item) {
            return $item->product;
        })->filter(function ($item) {
            return $item->discount === 1;
        });
```

also, I have tried:

```
        if ($coupon) {
            foreach ($order->items as $item) {
                foreach ($item->product as $product)
                    if ($product->discount === 1) {
                        $order->items()->update([
                            "coupen_id" => $coupen->id,
                        ]);
                    }
            }

        }

and it doesn't work.
```

How I must update the coupon_id of products by `$order->items()->update([])` that are discountable.

Comment: Did you try whereIn clause brother, `$order->items()->whereIn('product_id',$product_ids_array)->update([])`

Comment: thank you, it was a good point. I set my worked code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can skip loop with `whereIn`:

```
//Pluck product ids from collection
$product_ids_array = $discountable_products->pluck('id')->toArray();

//if $coupon->id is constant
$order->items()->whereIn('product_id', $product_ids_array )->update([
            "coupen_id" => $coupon->id,
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if ($coupon) {
        foreach ($discountable_products as $product) {
            $order->items()->where('product_id', $product->id)->update([
                "coupen_id" => $coupon->id,
            ]);
        }
    }
```